# Calculating 'Diagonal Distance' in 3 dimensions for A* path-finding heuristic

Tags: python, path-finding, a-star, heuristics

I'm running A* Path finding over a 3D grid of data.  Available movements are the 26 surrounding nodes (i.e. you can move diagonally)  I've been using euclidean distance as the heuristic and this works well but I'd also like to try 'diagonal distance' to see how that works (and if there are any speed gains)

I've found some logic online to do this in 2 dimensions...

```
function heuristic(node) =
dx = abs(node.x - goal.x)
dy = abs(node.y - goal.y)
return D * (dx + dy) + (D2 - 2 * D) * min(dx, dy)
```

..,where D is the north/east/south/west distance (for example 1m) and D2 is the diagonal distance (for example sqrt(2))

I'm not exactly sure how to convert this to 3 dimensions - so any help would be greatly appreciated

As an extra question (as this is how much grid is in reality...) suppose nodes on the x and y axis are 5m apart, but 2m apart on the z axis...how would the formula work then?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: My guess would be, move 3-diagonally until either X, Y, or Z are correct, then it devolves into the 2D problem (above).

Answer (score 3):

It can be extended to 3D relatively easily. It does require finding the "middle" of 3 values, there is a trick for that given that we have the minimum and maximum.

```
dx = absdiff(node.x, goal.x)
dy = absdiff(node.y, goal.y)
dz = absdiff(node.z, goal.z)
dmin = min(dx, dy, dz)
dmax = max(dx, dy, dz)
dmid = dx + dy + dz - dmin - dmax
```

This works for Python style integers and even for Java style `int`, for floats it can cause some rounding though.

Combine them like this:

```
return (D3 - D2) * dmin + (D2 - D1) * dmid + D1 * dmax
```

Answer (score -2):

am i right?

Depth camera show us the depth of object.
The depth data is a diagonal distance from the center of camera.
It is not a z-axis distance which is moving control.
Therefore, it has to be calculating using depth, pixel X and Pixel Y.
I know that we don't know the pysical unit of

Comment: Your answer is not clear at all. You shouldn't start an answer with a question asking if the answer is correct. Also, your last sentence is incomplete. Please edit the answer to be clearer.

Comment: This looks like a incomplete answer. Please improve it @Jaeyoung Lee.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30734097)